# Replace multiple occurences of substring with conditional substring that includes the original substring

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

Sorry for the long title, but I'm at a loss here as a beginner... possibly I can't find an existing solution because I don't know the terms to search for.

What I'm trying to do is replace all substrings in a string with some conditional substring that includes the original substring. An example might be more clear:

```
String answerIN = "Hello, it is me. It is me myself and I."
//should become something like: 
String answerOUT = "Hello, it is <sync:0> me. It is <sync:1> me myself and I"
```

So the substring "me"  should be replaced by itself plus some conditional thing. What I tried so far doesn't work because I keep on replacing the replaced substring. So I end up with:

```
String answerOUT = "Hello, it is <sync:0> <sync:1> me. It is <sync:0> <sync:1> me myself and I"
```

My code:

```
        String answerIN = "Hello, it is me. It is me myself and I.";
        String keyword = "me";
        int nrKeywords = 2; //I count this in the program but that's not the issue here

        if (nrKeywords != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < nrKeywords; i++){
                action = " <sync" + i + "> " + keyword;
                answerIN = answerIN.replace(keyword, action);
                System.out.println("New answer: " + answerIN);
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out how to NOT replace the substring-part of the string that was already replaced.

Answer (score 1):

`String#replace` will allways replace each occurence of the `String` you are looking for with what you want to replace it with. So that´s not possible with the regular `String#replace`, as there is no "only replace from here to there".

You could work with the `String`'s substring method in order to replace each occurence:

```
String input = "Hello, it is me. It is me myself and I.";
String output = "";
String keyword = "me";
int nextIndex = input.indexOf(keyword), oldIndex = 0, counter = 0;

while(nextIndex != -1) {
    output += input.substring(oldIndex, nextIndex-1) + " <sync:" + counter + "> ";
    oldIndex = nextIndex;
    nextIndex = input.indexOf(keyword, nextIndex+1);
    ++counter;
}
output += input.substring(oldIndex);
System.out.println(output);
```

O/P

```
Hello, it is <sync:0> me. It is <sync:1> me myself and I.
```